# Meteor - array item class added but how?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

I'm trying to learn Meteor js and working through a tutorial but cannot understand how a row is highlighted by the following:

- First an Array is returned via:

  ```
    {{# each player}}
    <li class="player {{selectedClass}}">{{name}} => {{score}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  ```

On initialization nothing is selected so the `selectedClass` function above doesn't return anything.

Then for when the user clicks a row there is a `click event`:

```
'click .player': function(){
   var playerId = this._id;
   Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
   var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
```

So I get that, as a result of the `click event` the selectedPlayer variable references the id of the row clicked.  But how're we then iterating through the array to add `selected` as a class of the correct row's `li` element?

i.e.
When the user selects a row it highlights the row selected by using the helper function and css class `.selected`:

```
selectedClass: function(){
    var playerId = this._id;
    var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
    if(playerId == selectedPlayer){
    return "selected";
```

My question is: when the user selects a row, where do we iterate through the array to add `selected` to the row selected and therefore allow it to be highlighted.

Apologies for the convoluted explanation.  It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `players` returns a cursor for iterating over every document fetched on the client, and there's 3 documents with the following values :

```
{_id: "ABC", name: "Alice", score: 15}
{_id: "DEF", name: "Bob", score: 10}
{_id: "GHI", name: "Claire", score: 5}
```

Let's rewrite the `{{#each}}` loop to see what's actually being rendered by Meteor Blaze.

```
<li class="player {{selectedClass}}">Alice => 15</li>
<li class="player {{selectedClass}}">Bob => 10</li>
<li class="player {{selectedClass}}">Claire => 5</li>
```

`{{name}}` and `{{score}}` are simply being replaced by the corresponding values in the current data context, because the `{{#each}}` block helper not only iterates over a collection, it also sets the data context of the content block to the currently iterated item.

`selectedClass` however, is a "computed" template helper, it does not simply return a field of the current data context, but has to compute its value dynamically.

If we replace the helper name with pseudo code we have the following :

```
<li class="player {{"ABC" == Session.get("selectedPlayer") ? "selected" : ""}}">Alice => 15</li>
<li class="player {{"DEF" == Session.get("selectedPlayer") ? "selected" : ""}}">Bob => 10</li>
<li class="player {{"GHI" == Session.get("selectedPlayer") ? "selected" : ""}}">Claire => 5</li>
```

I'm using the ternary operator to be more concise, note that you cannot write such Spacebars markup at the moment.

What you need to understand is that `selectedClass` is not a function iterating on an array to add the appropriate class on the selected row, it's a template helper being executed for each player document being iterated over by the `{{#each}}` block.

`selectedClass` is comparing the current data context _id (using `this._id` syntax because inside a template helper the `this` keyword is bound to the current data context) to the global `Session` variable containing the `_id` of the selected player.

If the two values match, then the `"selected"` string is returned, if it's not the case then an empty string is returned.

The list items classes are being assigned to `"player {{selectedClass}}"` so the currently selected item will have a class attribute with the following value : `"player selected"`.